# Implement interceptor just for one service or request - Angular Interceptors

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-http-interceptors, angular-httpclient

I would like to know if there is a way to implement interceptor just for one service or even one HTTP request? I want to implement it to send the token in the header but it is for logged in user, so not all of the requests need to have token.

```
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/

Angular CLI: 1.6.8
Node: 9.4.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.2.4
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.42
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.29
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.52
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.8
@schematics/angular: 0.1.17
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.10.0
```

Comment: If it's just for one http request, you may as well directly add the code to the service. But anyway, why don't you just add the header in the interceptor IF the user is logged in?

Comment: It's bothering to check and add the header in every service function. Why didn't I even think about checking it, thanks.

Comment: As you know REST API is stateless. Therefore you have to add access token to the header in each http request.